# Calling insecure endpoint from a website runs under HTTPS - nginx

Tags: rest, nginx, webserver, endpoint, content-security-policy

My application is running under HTTPS with a valid certificate from one of the known authorities. Unfortunately I am using a third party API which doesn't support HTTPS.

> The result is the known message Mixed content: mydomain.com requested an
>   insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint.

***Is it possible*** to add an exception to the web server to allow calling this API insecurely!! I am using Nginx BTW.

If not what what can be other possibilities to solve this problem.

**I have a solution but I don't like it because it will be a performance drawback:**

Implement an API which acts as proxy, receive the requests from the application through HTTPS and make the requests to the third party API throw HTTP.

Comment: Did my answer resolve the issue? If you need help with configuration, I can.

Comment: @khrm will give it a try tomorrow and update you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too had this issue. Everything on a page should come and request https if you are using https and don't want warning/errors. You don't need to implement an api to proxy if you are using nginx. Whatever you implement will be performance hit as you correctly surmise. Just use proxy pass in nginx.
In our configuration, we have :

```
location /thirdparty/ {
        proxy pass http://thirdpartyserver/;
 }
```

Notice the trailing slash in proxy pass, I keep all third party api which are http in https://myserver/thirdparty/requesturl. Trailing slash removes thirdparty while making request. So it becomes, http://thirdpartyserver/request

Official reference: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow mixed content, the individual users must allow it in their browsers. Allowing HTTP content from one source is enough to compromise the security of HTTPS, so browsers forbid mixed content by default. The solutions I see are:

1. Getting rid of HTTPS (which I would NOT recommend)
2. Doing what you suggested and proxying requests through (this still isn't great security-wise)
3. Get rid of the HTTP content

Google has some recommendations for developers under step 1 (but they are basically echoed above): https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content#step-1

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, I wouldn't git rid of HTTPS. gone through this article but didn't find what am looking for, posted this as someone might give another idea.

Comment: Yeah that article basically outlined what I said above. It's unfortunate from a usability standpoint but paramount from a security perspective that mixed-content is blocked